# Calculus of several variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, self-learning

I have problem in solving the definite integral of the following function:

$$f(x, y, z) = \int_0^z \int_0^y \int_0^x e^{-x-y-z} dx dy dz,  $$

All I know is the calculus for single variable. But with the addition of another variables, things get complicated.

Comment: I only see $x$ ( a single variable ) in your problem... also, welcome to the MSE!

Comment: It's very bad notation to use both $x$ in the bound on the integral and as the variable of integration.

Comment: Recognize that the integration variable is a dummy, and you should better write, say $f(x) = \int_0^x \mathrm{e}^{-u} \, \mathrm{d} u$

Comment: sorry don't know how to use symbols in this forum...

Comment: You treat them as constants.

Comment: Answer is $0$ by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, it is sort of "bad manners" to use a variable both as a dummy variable and as a bound. So your integral...
$$f(x, y, z) = \int_0^z \int_0^y \int_0^x e^{-x-y-z} \,dx \,dy \,dz$$
might be better written as...
$$f(x, y, z) = \int_0^z \int_0^y \int_0^x e^{-u-v-w} \,du \,dv \,dw$$

Now that said, this is an iterated integral meaning you tackle each integral, working from the inside outward, one at a time. First, with respect to $u$, then $v$, then $w$.

So first $\displaystyle \int_0^x e^{-u-v-w} \,du$. Treating $v$ and $w$ as constants, this is essentially like integrating something like $\int e^{-u+5}\,du$. So the antiderivative is $-e^{-u+5}$ or in your case $-e^{-u-v-w}$. Thus
$$ \int_0^x e^{-u-v-w} du = -e^{-u-v-w} \Bigg|_0^x = -e^{-x-v-w}-(-e^{0-v-w})$$ $$= e^{-v-w}-e^{-x-v-w} = (1-e^{-x})e^{-v-w}$$

This means that 
$$f(x, y, z) = \int_0^z \int_0^y \int_0^x e^{-u-v-w} \,du \,dv \,dw = \int_0^z \int_0^y (1-e^{-x})e^{-v-w} \,dv \,dw$$

We can then integrate with respect to $v$ and then $w$. These steps go essentially the same way so in the end we get
$$f(x, y, z) = \int_0^z \int_0^y \int_0^x e^{-u-v-w} \,du \,dv \,dw = (1-e^{-x})(1-e^{-y})(1-e^{-z})$$

Alternatively you can notice that the bounds of integration are independent from each other. So each can be treated as a constant. Because of this, this particular iterated integral can be "factored"...
$$f(x, y, z) = \int_0^z \int_0^y \int_0^x e^{-u-v-w} \,du \,dv \,dw =
\int_0^z \int_0^y \int_0^x e^{-u}e^{-v}e^{-w} \,du \,dv \,dw$$
$$ = \int_0^z e^{-w} \int_0^y e^{-v} \int_0^x e^{-u} \,du \,dv \,dw
=\left(\int_0^x e^{-u} \,du\right)
\left(\int_0^y e^{-v} \,dv\right)
\left(\int_0^z e^{-w} \,dw\right) $$ 
$$= (1-e^{-x})(1-e^{-y})(1-e^{-z})$$

Comment: Very well said. Tnx

Comment: Glad to help! I feel like I should give an extra warning about "factoring" iterated integrals. While this is a nice shortcut for a good number of problems, it cannot always be done. You can only "pull out integrals" when the formula and bounds do not depend on the variables whose integrals you're pulling them through. In particular, this "trick" always applies when you have constant bounds and the function you are integrating itself factors. :)

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x, y, z) = \int_0^z \left(\int_0^y\left( \int_0^x e^{-x'-y'-z'} 
dx'\right) dy'\right) dz'
\\=
\int_0^z \left(\int_0^y [-e^{-x'-y'-z'}]_{x'=0}^x dy'\right) dz'
\\=\int_0^z \left(\int_0^y (1-e^{-x})e^{-y'-z'}dy'\right) dz'
\\=\int_0^z \left((1-e^{-x})[-e^{-z'-y'}]_{y'=0}^y 
\right) dz'
\\= \int_0^z (1-e^{-x})(1-e^{-y})e^{-z'} dz'= 
(1-e^{-x})(1-e^{-y})(1-e^{-z})
  $$

Comment: can the downvoter explain?

Comment: Perhaps the down voter didn't notice you're using different variables.

Comment: I sometimes wonder why writing answers that do not seem to be read.

Comment: 'been there.${}{}$

Comment: @mookid Tnx! Your answer is correct, however I can only vote once.

Comment: that's ok ;)\\\